# Issue with referencing the .Net core class library project in Asp.Net core project

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

I am referencing a .Net core class library project in my asp.net core application. The reference in the web application fails.Could somebody tell me what the problems is. I am posting both of my Project.jsons files. The entry  "CustomerOrder.Data": "1.0.0-*"  in  asp.net json file is the reference of the class library project

.NetCore Class library project : netstandard1.6

Asp.Net Core                   : netcoreapp1.0

I am getting the following error message

Error   NU1001  The dependency CustomerOrder.Data >= 1.0.0-* could not be resolved.

**.NetCore class library project - Project.Json**

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "CustomerOrder.Model": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions": "1.1.0",
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.1"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.6": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"

    }
  }
}
```

**.Asp.Net .NetCore project - Project.Json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.0.1",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.AngularServices": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0",
    "CustomerOrder.Data": "1.0.0-*" },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final",
    "Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools": "1.0.0-preview2-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "appsettings.json",
      "ClientApp/dist",
      "node_modules",
      "Views",
      "web.config",
      "wwwroot"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [
      "npm install",
      "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js --env.prod",
      "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod"
    ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  },

  "tooling": {
    "defaultNamespace": "CustomerOrder.Web"
  }
}
```

**After updating the version**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "version": "1.1.0",
      "type": "platform"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.AngularServices": "1.1.0-beta-000001",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": {
      "version": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
      "type": "build"
    },
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.0.0"
  },

  "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.DotNet.Watcher.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.1": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },

  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },

  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },

  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "appsettings.json",
      "ClientApp/dist",
      "node_modules",
      "Views",
      "web.config",
      "wwwroot"
    ]
  },

  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [
      "npm install",
      "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --config webpack.config.vendor.js --env.prod",
      "node node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --env.prod"
    ],
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  },

  "tooling": {
    "defaultNamespace": "CustomerOrder.Web"
  }
}
```

Comment: One error is that you're mixing the packages versions. Eg. `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.0.0"` and `"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.1"`. Try to use `1.0.1` for all aspnetcore related packages.

Comment: Did you mean version 1.1.0 as didnt as i get error when i put 1.0.1 and neither does that version come up in intellisense

Comment: do you have .net core 1.1.0 installed? If yes, then use `1.1.0`. Remember to update your project.json. Eg: `netcoreapp1.1` and `"version": "1.1.0",`

Comment: I tried as you suggested.changed the version    netcoreapp1.1 and "version": "1.1.0". It does allow me to reference the class library project without any error. But when I press F5 I get the following error message. 
This site can’t be reached
localhost refused to connect.  For some reason it doesnt allow me to debug or attach the process. But if I revert the versions to what it was and remove the reference to the class library project , I am able to debug the web application. Dont know what is happening

Comment: Try to create an new project. It will be created with 1.0.1 or 1.0.0 version. Update to 1.1.0 and run to make sure it's working. Then, create a class library and also update to 1.1.0. Then create the references and test it.

Comment: I tried what you said. Created a new webproject, upgraded the version and ran. I get the same error which is quite strange. This site can’t be reached localhost refused to connect

Comment: I have updated the post  with the project.json that contains the new version. Not sure why that affects the debugging of the application. At this point I havent referenced any class library either. Could you copy this to your local machine and try out if it happens for you as well.

Comment: Did you create with the API Template? That one which already comes with the API ValueController.

Comment: I have been using this template http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2016/10/04/angular2-template-for-visual-studio/

Comment: That template doesnt have api. However I add api controller to it.

Comment: The reason why I using this template as it is designed for angular 2 which I am planning to use it for my frontend

Comment: I don't know this template. I recommend you to create a .Net Core Web Application (.Net Core) and choose the Web API template. This way, you already have a ValueController that should work. Then you can see how it creates the project.json for you. Also, check this [tutorial](https://github.com/fabriciokoch/AspnetcoreAngular) for .net core + angular. It's for Angular 1 but there you can see how to create a app from scratch.

Comment: I was pretty curious to try out what you suggested but it resulted in the same problem.In your example I believe you arent changing the versions and using the default template. In my scenario I need to change the reference in order for the refrerence to the class library work

Comment: Yes, the tutorial is a little old. That's why it's using 1.0.0. It was just for you to have a step-by-step example. To figure out what's your error, it's better to create the .Net Core Web Application (.Net Core) and choose the Web API template. Then, check if it works. After this, upgrade to 1.1.0, check if still works. Then, you'll have a project.json to compare with the project.json from your Angular2 template.

Comment: Yes. As I mentioned in the previous comment. I did the same but it resulted in the same issue. I created a new .net core web application using the web api template.

Comment: ok, but it worked before updating to 1.1.0?

Comment: Yes. The web application works in isolation when using the angular template as well the standard template. Both the templates have same version when created for the first time. Both have problems when the version is upgraded. Both dont work in isolation after the upgrade. So there is some  issue with the versioning. Hence I have shared the project.json file in my post which contains the latest version that doesnt work. Could somebody try it out and let me know  what the issue could be ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been resolved now. I had applied "win10-x64" to the following framework section and it worked.

```
 "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "win10-x64"
      ]
    }
  },
```